# Checking for a target product within a list(recursion)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
def can_make_product(p, vals):
    if len(vals)==1:
       if p==vals[0]:
           return True
       else:
           return False

    for i in range(len(vals)):
       for k in range(i,len(vals)):

           if vals[i] * vals[k]==p:
               return True

    return False
```

`p` is the product that I'm looking for in the list `vals`. However, the above code only works for multiples of 2 numbers at a time and not for all possible subsets. Is there a much easier way using recursion?
For example, given  `p=81`, and the list `[2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9]`, `3×3×9=81`, it should return `true`.

Comment: Must you do your own recursion, or can you use a module such as `itertools` to handle the recursion for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def can_make_product(p, vals):
    # base case empty list: n**0 == 1 for all n
    try:
        head, tail = vals[0], vals[1:]
    except IndexError:
        return p == 1
    # recursive step: try tail of vals with/without head
    if not p % head and can_make_product(p//head, tail):
        return True
    return can_make_product(p, tail)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)